# Comparing 2 variables characters (Python)

Tags: python, string

I want to compare 2 string variables and return the number of characters that are shared between the 2 strings. So `"work"` and `"what"` would return "1/4" since 1 out of 4 letters (only `w` in this example) are the same between the 2 strings.

Comment: What do you return if they are not equal in length?

Comment: Any code you wrote already? Even if it is not working, post it so we can start from there.

Comment: "Number of same letters" means, same letter in same position? Or just generally letters that appear in any position in both words?

Comment: Just the number of same letters and all the words in my list are equal length, sadly idk what the coding would be i only have coding for the rest of the program

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the number of letters that appear in both words in the same position:

```
sum(1 for a, b in zip(word1, word2) if a == b)
```

`zip` gives you an iterator for each character in both words at the same time, and you simply sum `1` for each time they match.

This gives you the generally shared letters between both words in any position:

```
len(set(word1) & set(word2))
```

This creates two sets of letters, takes the intersection of both sets, and tells you how big that intersection is.

Comment: Or just: `sum(a==b for a, b in zip(word1, word2))`

Comment: ahhh okok ty very much for the help ill see if this works! :)

Comment: @schwobaseggl Arguably, yes, but I dislike the implicit boolean → int conversion… :)

Comment: @deceze Certainly, yours is more transparent for a beginner and, adding the condition to the generator, teaches another aspect :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for something like this?

```
a = "hello"
print(list(a))

b = "hell"

counter=0
for x in list(a):
    if x in list(b):
    counter+=1

print(str(counter)+"/"+str(len(list(b))))
```

This  is taking the string stored in variable a, looping through the characters and comparing to the string stored in variable b. Finally; it prints the number of characters in a that were also in b over the length of the string stored in b.

Answer (score 0):

You might what to consider using `difflib` as it seems to cover your usecase but also extends it to strings of different lengths.

### Example 1

```
import difflib

sequence_matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(a='work', b='what')

sequence_matcher.ratio() # 0.25
```

### Example 2

```
import difflib

sequence_matcher = difflib.SequenceMatcher(a='work', b='works')

sequence_matcher.ratio() # 0.889
```